# Non printable character matching using Regular expression

Tags: regex, ant

I am trying to write an `ant` task that removes all lines that match a regular expression.

What I am doing right now:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="import com.xyz.abc.123.*"/>
    <substitution expression=""/>
    <fileset dir="/my/custom/directory">
        <include name="*.java"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

This leaves a blank line and does not delete it, which is understandable to me. But when I modify the regex to this:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="import com.xyz.abc.123.*\\n"/>
    <substitution expression=""/>
    <fileset dir="/my/custom/directory">
        <include name="*.java"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

It does not even match the regex. Any suggestions on how to attack this issue?

One more noob question: when I used this regex `import com.xyz*` it could not match the pattern, the current regex is matching. Doesn't `prefix*` find patterns with the prefix as `prefix`?

PS: I would not want to run another task to remove all empty lines because that will mess up formatting and will delete empty lines which I want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\\n` for a line break, whereas you should have been using `\n`. This matches the UNIX line break. If you are interested in removing linebreaks, no matter if Windows or UNIX, you can also use `\r?\n`. Make sure to not use the flag `byline="true"`. This will match your text line by line, but does not include line breaks:

```
<replaceregexp byline="false" flags="g">
    <regexp pattern="import com\.xyz\.abc\.123\r?\n"/>
```

*You might have seen, that the dot character `.` is escaped here. A dot character means "every character" in regex. Because you actually want to match a dot here, you need to escape it.*

---

The `*` character says, that the preceding token (usually one letter) can be matched either 0 or more than 0 times (but greedy). In your case `prefix*`, the following samples would match:

```
prefi
prefix
prefixxxxx
prefixxxxxxxxx
```

If you want to group this term together, you can use a capturing or non-capturing group:

```
(prefix)*    -> capturing group
(?:prefix)*  -> non-capturing group
```

I saw, that you have used `.*`. When you are deactivating `byline`, it can be dangerous to use `.*`, because it matches any character and as many as possible (possibly until the end of the file). To gather the fewest character as possible you can use a question mark after it: `.*?`

If your import statement has a variable end of the statement (but ends at the linebreak), you can use the following regular expression:

```
<regexp pattern="import com\.xyz\.abc\..*?\r?\n"/>
```

This would match any of the following

```
import com.xyz.abc.  [ line break ]
import com.xyz.abc.a  [ line break ]
import com.xyz.abc.bc;  [ line break ]
import com.xyz.abc.def23fewvgsdvds;;;;  [ line break ]
```

Comment: Thanks, i read up on the basics after reading your answer.  I did not know the working of dot metacharacter and was treating it as a literal. I had with the wrong knowledge of dot being a literal had put the "*.java" inside the fileset include name but it worked. Now, i replaced with <include name=".*\.java"/> to find all java files, but this doesnt seem to work.